# changing a recursive function to an iteration

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

I wanted to create a `<ufunc>` chainer, and is something I implemented using the `functors.reduce` function. For example:

```
from functools import reduce
fns1 = [np.cos, np.sin, np.tan]
x = reduce(  lambda f, f1: lambda m: f1(f(m)) , fns1, lambda m: m )
x(0.5)
```

Although this is very simple, I wanted to make code that is more readable. So I generated an iterative version:

```
def fnLong(fnList):

    curFn = lambda m: m
    for f in fnList:
        currF = lambda m: f(currF(m))

    return currF
```

This function actually creates an infinite loop. I believe that both functions should be exactly the same, but apparently not. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem originates from `lambda` expression because it is resolved at call-time. This feature results in various issues when you create bunch of `lambda`s inside `for loop`. In your code you use `lambda` inside `lambda` inside `for loop` and then return resulting nested `lambda` to call it later.

You may fix the problem like this:

```
def fnLong(fnList):

    currF = lambda m: m
    for f in fnList:
        currF = lambda m, f=f, currF=currF: f(currF(m))

    return currF
```

`currF=currF` and `f=f` added to specify arguments (bind arguments) for every `lambda` expressions inside `for loop` during the creation of this very `lambda`. This solution works because arguments' default values are created during function creation (definition) not during function call. `currF=currF` allows to avoid recursion, `f=f` allows to avoid usage of only the last function in `fnList`.

In my opinion it is hard to say if this version is more readable than the original one.